# iOS 13 UIBarButtonItem color in dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor, ios-darkmode

My UIBarButtonItem image doesn't change its color when switching between dark and light mode.

I set the color programmatically and expected it to change between black and white when switching the mode. 
At least it works with the tintColor of my NavigationBar.

I set:

```swift
myBarButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

and the image of the button stays white in dark AND in light mode.

On the other hand, the following is black in light mode and white in dark mode:

```swift
navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Why does it behave differently and how can I add this functionality to my UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIColor.white` is *not* a dynamic color. It will be white regardless of the appearance setting. If you want a color that is different depending on the appearance, you need to take one of the new dynamic system colors (e.g., `UIColor.systemBackground` would be white in light and black in dark mode), or create a color asset with different color values for light and dark appearance in an asset catalog.

Here is more on the new system colors: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color#dynamic-system-colors

Comment: Thank you! UIColor.label is the new color I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using iOS 13's new appearance API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

Example:

```
let navStyle = UINavigationBarAppearance()

let buttonStyle = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
// Change properties of buttonStyle here with dynamic colours such as UIColor.label.
style.buttonAppearance = buttonStyle
style.doneButtonAppearance = ...
style.backButtonAppearance = ...

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navStyle
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = ...
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = ...
```